# Prove that if $A \vartriangleleft G$ is abelian, then $A$ has a complement in $G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group. Suppose that the intersection of all of the maximal subgroups of $G$ is trivial. Prove that if $A \vartriangleleft G$ is abelian, then there exist $U \subseteq G$ such that $AU=G$ and $A \cap U=1$.

Tell me some hints.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: have you thought about $G/H$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $G$ be a minimal counterexample. We can choose $A$ such that $|A|$ is minimal. Hence we can find $M \le G$ such that $G=MA$ and $M\cap A\ne 1$. We can choose $M \ne G$ because the intersection of all maximal subgroups is trivial. Let $B=M \cap A$. Clearly $B \ne A$ by our choice. Since $A$ is abelian and $G=MA$, we get $B$ is a normal subgroup in $G$, i.e. $B$ satisfies all requirement of $A$.

By minimality of $A$, there exists $M_1$ such that $G=M_1B$ and $M_1 \cap B=1$. Hence $M=M \cap G=B(M \cap M_1)$. So $G=MA=(M_1\cap M)BA=(M\cap M_1)A$. Now $(M\cap M_1 )\cap A=M_1 \cap B=1$, a contradiction.

Comment: (1) How do we get the existence of $\;M\;$? Counter-example means that either there is no such $\;M\;$ or else there is but its intersection with $\;A\;$ isn't trivial. (2) $\;B\neq A$ "by our choice"...I think $\;B=A\iff A\subset M\implies AM=M\neq G\;$ . What choice? (3) How does normality of $\;B\;$ follows?

Comment: Since frattini subgroup is trivial, we can conclude that such $M$ exists.

Comment: The first paragraph is subtle (I think I would explain it differently), but correct. "Let $M$ be any maximal subgroup that does not contain $A$. Such a subgroup exists because $A \not\leq \Phi(G)$."

Comment: This is some tricky reasoning: as I understand it, $|A|$ is minimal among all counterexamples (not $|G|$), so for every subgroup $U \subseteq G$, either $UA \neq G$ or $A \cap U \neq 1$, and since $\Phi(G) = 1$, there exists $M$ maximal satisfying the latter, but eventually $M \cap M_1$ satisfies neither, which is the contradiction. Definitely +1

Comment: @DonAntonio your question 1) 2) follow as Babgen. 3) Clearly B is normal in M for A is normal in G. B is normal in A for A is abelian. Note G=MA, we see B is normal in G.

Comment: Ah, "maximal" being the main, missing word there, @JackSchmidt...indeed.

Comment: The answer is, I think, correct though rather sloppy and missing some rather important words, even if intended as blurry hint.